# How integrate Cypress and Cucumber with TestRail using javascript?

Tags: javascript, cypress-cucumber-preprocessor, testrail

In the google there is no information about how we can integrate Cypress-cucumber with TestRail. Maybe someone know?

I had found information about how integrate cypress with testrail, but there is nothing about cypress-cucumber with testrail

Comment: You might want to have a look at Railflow (https://railflow.io) - a commercial platform for integration of various test framework with TestRail. If your cypress-cucumber framework can produce cucumber JSON reports - it can be uploaded into TestRail with Railflow NPM CLI or Jenkins/TeamCity plugin.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this version of cypress cucumber preprocessor:

- "cypress-cucumber-preprocessor": "^4.3.1"

With this TestRail reporter:

- "hanoi-cypress-testrail-reporter": "^2.2.0"

This is the last version this combination worked well for me, because bundled ".features" files support was discontinued on the cucumber preprocessor versions which were released after the project handover, and the reporter started to create a separate test run on TestRail for every feature file in the absence of support for the removed feature, when I wanted to run all feature files in a directory in one go.

It was announced [here](https://github.com/badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor/issues/689) that a comeback for the bundled ".features" file support is unlikely on preprocessor side, and there have been no updates or a fix for the issue on the reporter side ever since. If you can live without updating to the latest version of the preprocessor, then I would say go for it.

Last but not least, to save yourself from the hassle;
make sure to follow the configuration instructions for the respective version of Cypress Cucumber Preprocessor (https://github.com/badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor/tree/v4.3.1), because the latest one will be different.